# difference between extern "C" char Table[256][256]; and extern char Table[256][256];

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In visual studio code compiled successfully with

```
extern "C"  char Table[256][256];
```

and if I replace the above code with

```
extern char Table[256][256];
```

visual studio starts to give me unresolved external errors for Table?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141390/extern-and-extern-c-for-variables

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are two unrelated meanings of the keyword [`extern`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/extern).

The first one is the [language linkage specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage), which makes the variable interoperable with C.

The second one is the [storage class specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), which declares that the variable is defined elsewhere (which it wasn't, hence the "undefined reference" error).

You could actually use both to declare a variable with C linkage that is defined elsewhere:

```
extern "C" extern char Table[256][256];
```

Comment: @anatolyg well, only if that's what you need. Just noting that two `extern` keywords can exist on the same declaration.

Comment: `extern "C" extern` a classic from the people who more recently brought us `noexcept(noexcept(...))` and are soon to bring us `requires requires`....

Comment: @StoryTeller don't forget about `long long`, template template parameters, and I'm sure we skirted pretty close to `auto auto` ;)